# best way to track changes in a text file?

Tags: version-control, text

I would like to do the following:
for a paper I am going to write, I want to be able to track all the changes made to the text (file) in such a way, that in the end I can tell for every sentence / word when it was written (date and time).

I haven't used any revision control system so far, but I suppose this is the easiest way to do it. however, the question is, how can I automate the whole process and make it as convenient and precise as possible?
what I could do is write some kind of script / plugin for my text editor that saves the file and commits the changes to the revision control system at the same time. it would be okay to do that after every new sentence, I guess; but let's say I wanted to do it for every word -- it would be really bothersome having to hit ctrl-s every second ... the only thing I can think of at the moment is try to find a way to let the text editor run the script every time I hit the space bar / perdiod key.

would you say that is the easiest way to do it or do I fail to see some better possibilty?

ideas appreciated.
thanks!

**EDIT**
I just found http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/ for notepad++ which I can use to look for " "s in the keystrokes quite easily.

Comment: It depends to the text editor you use. I can't imagine it is possible to override Notepad's `Ctrl-S` :) version controls basically support that feature. e.g `svn blame -v filename`, or `cvs annotate filename`. If you work on Windows, you can use TortoiseCVS/SVN using the context menu, if you are on mac, you can make a custom Finder plugin. But the text editor you use is matter, if you want to combine save + commit to the version control (not a good idea, btw).

Comment: I want to do this with my todo.txt file, this file changes a lot and it would be useful to see the status of the file on a certain moment in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend 2 things:
- FileSystemWatcher from System.IO namespace
- WMI

I found a nice sample in my bookmarks using FSW http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/FileSystemWatcher.aspx